# Why is there an element that is not being displayed?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am practicing creating a randomly generating integers in an array, then randomizing the elements in the array. All is well when I print the numbers, but there seems to be one element that does not print when I am displaying the randomized elements. Is there a step I am leaving out?

```
public class shufflingArrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] myList = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Numbers:");
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        myList[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.print(myList[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\nRandomized:");

    for (int i = myList.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        //Generate index j randomly with 0 <= j <= i
        int j = (int)(Math.random() * (i + 1));

        //Swap myList[i]; with myList[j]
        int temp = myList[i];
        myList[i] = myList[j];
        myList[j] = temp;
        System.out.print(myList[i] + " ");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `for` loop has condition `i > 0`, which means when `i == 0` it will terminate and not print out the first array element.

However, if you're doing the Fisher-Yates shuffle, as it appears, you do indeed need to go from `myList.length-1` to 1, so your initial code was correct. You then can't print out all the elements in the array from the same loop, so either use another loop after to print out the elements, or add `System.out.print(myList[0]);` after.

Comment: Thank you. for such a small thing I was not able to realize where or what the mistake was. I changed it to  `i > -1` and it printed like I wanted. Why is this?

Comment: With `i > -1`, it then executes for `i == 0`, so it can print that element too.

Answer (score 2):

Ex: `for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--)`

will run the `for` loop when `i = 4, 3, 2, 1` only and not when `i = 0`, because the condition there is `i > 0`. Change the `i > 0` condition in `for (int i = myList.length - 1; i > 0; i--)` to `i >= 0` and you will get what you want.

Comment: This did fix my code, thank you. Why does `i > -1` and `i >= 0` both work the same for this case?